# Why is my Meta profile showing 0 score when I have over 10?

Tags: support, tags, profile-page

If you go on [my profile](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/users/310476/daniil-manokhin?tab=profile) on meta all tags have a core of 0. Whereas if you click on some one then tags that score is over 10!

Why is this?

Answer (score 3):

The tags score only counts **non-wiki answers**.

In your case, you asked 9 questions (not counted for tags score) and posted 2 answers (counted for tags score). As of current writing, [your tags score](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/users/310476/daniil-manokhin?tab=tags) correctly show `discussion` as -1 from the total of both of your answers.

> [image: non-wiki answers for tag score]